# How to find the derivative of the function $y=5^{-1/x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$y=5^{-1/x}$$

Help would be so greatly appreciated :] It's another homework problem...I unfortunately was not present during the lecture for these types of problems. I'm guessing from the $-1/x$ there would be a $\ln()$ in the answer?

Comment: Is that $5^{-1/x}$, or $\frac{5^{-1}}x$? (I’d just about bet on the former, but let’s make sure.)

Comment: definitely the first one :]

Comment: I bet the goal is to find the derivative of a function, not the derivative of a question.

Comment: There's examples on how to do this here just for possible reference http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LogDiff.aspx

Comment: Jonas: Too bad I already asked that question (which is why I said of this question not this function). Thanks.

Comment: @bkaifos15: The new title is rather unhelpful but makes sense.  A title can be used to indicate what the question is (roughly at least) without having to click on it.  I will try to improve this.

Comment: Cool deal! Thank you! :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s of the form $a^u$, where $u$ is some function of $x$. One of the basic differentiation formulas is

$$\frac{d}{dx}a^x=a^x\ln a\;;$$

combine that with the chain rule, since the exponent isn’t just $x$, and you get

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=5^{-1/x}(\ln 5)\left[-\frac1x\right]'\;.$$

Now you need the derivative of $-\frac1x$. Write it as $-x^{-1}$, and you see that all you need is the power rule:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=5^{-1/x}(\ln 5)\left[-\frac1x\right]'=5^{-1/x}(\ln 5)x^{-2}=\frac{\ln 5}{x^25^{1/x}}$$

(among many possible final forms).

Comment: Thanks again! Definitely Helpful!

Comment: @bkaifos15: My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

This has the form $a^{g(x)}$, where $a$ is a constant and $g(x)$ is some function of $x$. $$\frac{d}{dx}(a^{g(x)})=a^{g(x)} \cdot \ln(a) \cdot g'(x)$$

Don't forget to take the derivative of the exponent $g(x)$ by the chain rule.

You have
$$y = 5^{-\frac{1}{x}}$$
$$y' = 5^{-\frac{1}{x}} \cdot \ln(5) \cdot \frac{1}{x^2}$$

Comment: This is a little off. First of all that first equation is wrong $\frac{d}{dx}(a^x) = a^x ln(a)$. There is no $dx$ term at the end. Secondly your final answer includes ln(x). It should be ln(5).

Comment: What you mean to say is that $\frac{d}{dx} a^{g(x)} = a^{g(x)}ln(a)*g'(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the chain rule. So start by differentiating $5^{-1/x}$ with respect to $-1/x$ then multiple by the derivative of $-1/x$ with respect to $x$.

$\frac{d}{dx} = 5^{-1/x}ln(5)*1/x^2$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
$$
y = 5^{- \frac{1}{x}} = \exp \left[ - \frac{1}{x} \cdot \ln(5) \right].
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}
&= \exp \left[ - \frac{1}{x} \cdot \ln(5) \right] \cdot
   \frac{d}{dx} \left[ - \frac{1}{x} \cdot \ln(5) \right]
   \quad (\text{By the Exponential Chain Rule.}) \\
&= 5^{- \frac{1}{x}} \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \left[ - \frac{1}{x} \cdot \ln(5) \right] \\
&= 5^{- \frac{1}{x}} \cdot \frac{1}{x^{2}} \cdot \ln(5) \\
&= \frac{\ln(5)}{5^{\frac{1}{x}} x^{2}}.
\end{align}